# Movieclip width changes instead of height

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working in Flash Builder 4.5 in pure Actionscript 3.0

I have a movieclip (swc) , I am doing the following :

```
_visualItem.bgMiddle.height     = 200;
```

bgMiddle is an independant clip only has a single shape in it. On debugging the height remains the same (2.2) but the width changes to 5111. Haven't been able to track it down.

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: I don't think there's enough info in here for anyone to give you a proper answer. Have you tried using Monster Debugger? I find that's a good debugger for visual changes/issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly some transforms applied to any of the DisplayObjectContainers higher up in the display tree could be affecting the item you're trying to change?